# Obtener el nombre de la columna en consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Al hacer una consulta:
SELECT  variables, cantidad, comunidad FROM privado.
arroja una serie de cifras, por ejemplo, 252.
quiero saber a que columna correspondería este importe (si a variables, comunidad o cantidad),

Comment: Tu pregunta actualmente no es clara y es muy amplia. Lectura recomendada: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794)

Comment: Que pregunta tan rara. Normalmente tu haces el select y el DBMS te muestra de forma estructurada las cabeceras con sus respectivos valores. Tal vez no te estas explicando bien. Reformula tu pregunta.

Comment: Falta reformular la pregunta, pero puedo darte un ejemplo para que veas...

Answer (score 0):

Esto es para aclarar el modo en que está visualizando el OP...
Se borrara de ser necesario.

En la siguiente imagen, puedes ver como creo una tabla de prueba, e inserto algunos datos.
Creo la tabla con 2 columnas, `id` y `title`
Inserto 6 filas con datos, y luego hago un select all.
Abajo, donde está la `salida` puedes ver como el `select`  ha devuelto el nombre de las columnas por si solo y los datos que inserte anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]